# Select column from another table based on matching condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that have time-series data in the following form. I want to select all of the columns of TABLE1 and an additional column `Limit_At_Time` which is the value of the `Limit` column of TABLE2 for the row which has the most recent Date (relative to TABLE1.Date)

TABLE1:

```
Customer_ID   Date         Amount
1             01/01/2019   5
2             02/05/2019   15
```

TABLE2:

```
Customer_ID   Date         Limit
1             12/05/2018   10
1             12/25/2018   20
2             01/05/2019   30
2             03/08/2019   50
```

Result:

```
Customer_ID   Date         Amount      Limit_At_Time
1             01/01/2019   5           20
2             02/05/2019   15          30
```

The closest I have gotten is selecting a `previous_date` column with this query:

```
SELECT *, 
(SELECT MAX(Date) FROM TABLE2 t2
   WHERE t2.Date < t1.Date 
   AND t2.Customer_ID = t1.Customer_ID)
as previous_date
FROM TABLE1 AS t1
```

This gets me the date of the event from TABLE2 that I am interested in for each TABLE1 row, but I need to extract the `Limit` column value of the row that contains that `previous_date`.

How can I achieve the result that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.limit
        from table2 t2
        where t2.date <= t1.date
        order by t2.date desc
        limit 1
       ) as Limit_At_Time
from table1 t1;
```

Usually in these types of problems, the comparison is `<=` rather than `<`, so I used that.  Of course, the exact equivalent to your query is `<`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your subquery as a `JOIN` condition between `table1` and `table2` which will then allow you to get the `Limit` value from `table2`:

```
SELECT t1.Customer_ID, t1.Date, t1.Amount, t2.Limit
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.Customer_ID = t1.Customer_ID
              AND t2.Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM table2 t2b
                             WHERE t2b.Date < t1.Date 
                             AND t2b.Customer_ID = t1.Customer_ID)
```

Output:

```
Customer_ID Date        Amount  Limit
1           2019-01-01  5       20
2           2019-02-05  15      30
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jV4VHrhkQL2Z7zbnViDAhU/1)